# Web Api MVC binding FormDataCollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have a Jquery Ajax call more or like below

```
 $.ajax(url, {
         type: httpMethod,
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         data: '{name:"abc",age:23,address:"29 judd ce"}',
```

**The web api action is**

```
  public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] FormDataCollection data)
        {
```

However the parameter 'data' is always null.

Is this a web api limitation or am i doing it the wrong way

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a view model instead:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}
```

that your controller action will take:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(UserViewModel model)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Darin  Wondering if there is a way without using viewmodel?

Comment: You could always read from the request or write some custom binder or something but that would be insane especially when you already have everything needed built directly into the framework.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible

```
 $.ajax("http://localhost:57281/api/Values", {
                    type: "POST",
                    data: '{name:"abc",age:23,address:"29 judd ce"}',
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                });



//POST api/values
public void Post([FromBody]FormDataCollection value)
{

}
```

Also works without `[FromBody]`
But you will get only ONE pair of key/value

Better use something like that

```
  $.ajax("http://localhost:57281/api/Values", {
                    type: "POST",
                    data: 'name=abc&age=23&address=29 judd ce',
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                });
```

& is used as a separator for each pair